# Writing to previous realm object instead of next

Tags: ios, swift, object, realm, new-operator

I'm completely new in Realm and I'm trying to add some data ty my database. I have a trainings which consist of exercises. Every training has id, date and list of exercises. In my table view I create two trainings and every has its own id, after that I'm adding some exercises to first one and when I'm trying to add to second one I get an error: "Attempting to create an object of type 'TrainingExercise' with an existing primary key value 'Thruster'." I don't understand why it tries to add this to previous training. I get training by id from database and I checked if the right id is passed to function and that's it. But when I put breakpoint the id of training is previous and I can't understand the reason of this. Could somebody help me to solve this? 
Here is my training model:

```
    class Training: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var date = NSDate()
    var exercises = RealmSwift.List<TrainingExercise>()

    convenience init(date: NSDate, exercise: TrainingExercise) {
        self.init()
        self.date = date
        self.exercises.append(exercise)
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Here is my exercise model:

```
 class TrainingExercise: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    let sets = RealmSwift.List<GymSet>()


    convenience init(name: String, gymSet: GymSet) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.sets.append(gymSet)
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
}

class GymSet: Object {


    @objc dynamic var reps: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var kilos: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var time: String = ""

}
```

And here's function which i use to add exercises to a training

```
func addExerciseForTraining(trainingId: Int, exercise: TrainingExercise) {

    let training = getTrainingById(id: trainingId)

    try? database.write {
        training.exercises.append(exercise)
    }

    try? database.write {
        database.create(Training.self, value: training, update: true)
    }
}


func getTrainingById(id: Int) -> Training {
    let training = database.object(ofType: Training.self, forPrimaryKey: id)

    return training!
}
```

Comment: Can you add GymSet class code please?

Comment: Be careful with the relationships in Realm, they are not the same as on a real database. What I think it happens in your case, you are fetching data from database, create a new object that will be inserted and set the object from db to the new object. In this case, realm will create the new object and it will try to create a new one for the relation. What I suggest (just to see if it works) is to save the first object in the db without a relationship then update it with the object from db.

Comment: @RobertDresler i've added

Comment: I've tried to do this by database.add(training, update: true) but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set relationships between your classes right. So, try to replace your classes like this:

```
class Training: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = 0
    @objc dynamic var date = NSDate()
    var exercises = List<TrainingExercise>()
}

class TrainingExercise: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    var training = LinkingObjects(fromType: Training.self, property: "exercises")
    var sets = List<GymSet>()
}

class GymSet: Object {
    @objc dynamic var reps: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var kilos: Double = 0
    @objc dynamic var time: String = ""
    var exercise = LinkingObjects(fromType: TrainingExercise.self, property: "sets")
}
```

Now when you want to create new create it like this

```
let training = Training()
```

if you want to change any of its property use this for example

```
try? database.write {
    training.id = 1
}
```

and to add your training to database use this

```
try? database.write {
    database.add(training)
}
```

Comment: I do like this, but I add exercise to training later and that's the problem. I can't do this at this moment.